# Why doesn't Android Studio see updates right away?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 4.1.1. windows 7. I write in Java. I noticed this feature of the program. Changing something in code, layout or resources. I run the program and see that my changes have not appeared! First comes the thought that I was wrong somewhere. I start looking for an error. I don’t find it. I run the program again and it already works as it should. Now I'm used to it. The larger the program, the more often this happens. To be sure of the result, you have to run the program twice each time, because I'm not sure if this time all the changes took effect. It is very uncomfortable. Tell me why this is happening and how to solve this problem.